# How do i make global keyboard shortcuts work in all applications?

Tags: gnome, 21.10

I'm using Ubuntu 21.10 on a Thinkpad T14s with German keyboard layout. The application 1password has a global shortcut to open the password manager <kbd>Ctrl + Shift + Space</kbd>.

This shortcut works when most applications have focus (for example it works when using Slack or Google Chrome), but it does not work (meaning nothing happens) in other applications (for example Firefox or terminal).

I already tried to check if the apps where the shortcut does not work do intercept their own shortcut with that binding, but for at least terminal this is not the case.

Does anyone know what could cause this?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

You are using Ubuntu 21.10. I strongly suspect that you are also running the default, Wayland session. Check that on the "Settings" - "About" screen.

Wayland is a replacement for the Xorg display server, traditionally used to draw graphical elements on your screen. It strongly focuses on security. One thing is that applications are not allowed to know of each others. Applications are not allowed to grab key combinations desktop wide.

To support legacy applications, Wayland comes with xwayland. xwayland emulates an Xorg server. That your shortcut works when Google Chrome and Slack indicates that these are running on xwayland. Firefox and terminal natively run on Wayland, so these do not see this shortcut.

Currently, the only way you could have a global shortcut is if the application exposes some way to achieve what you want using the command line. Check the documentation for that. For example, the Albert launcher supports a command line option `toggle`. The only way to have that launcher always appear when hitting a shortcut key is by defining that shortcut key in "Settings" - "Keyboard" with the command `albert toggle`. The traditional way of setting a shortcut key, from within the program, does not anymore work for applications natively running on Wayland.

A workaround to circumvent the current limitations of Wayland is to leave it behind and move back to an Xorg session. Log out. On the log in screen, with the cursor in the password field, click the cog wheel and select "Ubuntu on Xorg" before loging back in.

Comment: Thanks for the fast and detailed answer! Tried out the workaround with albert, works perfectly !

Comment: For anyone else looking for 1Password specifically, the quick access window can indeed be launched from the CLI with `1password --quick-access`

Comment: this answer is well positioned at Google, so i wanted to inform that there's been active work on designing a [proper portal protocol for apps to request global shortcuts](https://github.com/flatpak/xdg-desktop-portal/pull/711) (for both X and Wayland). the protocol was approved and i believe is implemented by KDE, but [not Gnome](https://gitlab.gnome.org/GNOME/xdg-desktop-portal-gnome/-/issues/47). and in addition to implementing it there, apps would of course need to start using it